# Flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page that shows video. But when I complete the video and pop back to the previous page I get this bellow error. My app works all fine and good with no breaks, but this below error bothers me.

**setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build** is the error that I am unable to fix

I need help to fix this error.

**Here is my error:**

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for VideoPlayerController:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This VideoPlayerScreen widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already
in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build
phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the
framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be
built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
  VideoPlayerScreen
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
  Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#e44a5]

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4211:11)
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4226:6)
#2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1260:14)
#3      _VideoPlayerScreenState._listener (package:flow/widget/page/video_player.dart:52:7)
#4      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:209:21)
#5      ValueNotifier.value= (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:276:5)
#6      VideoPlayerController.pause (package:video_player/video_player.dart:360:5)
#7      _VideoPlayerScreenState.deactivate (package:/widget/page/video_player.dart:175:34)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)

The VideoPlayerController sending notification was:
  VideoPlayerController#619c5(VideoPlayerValue(duration: 0:10:55.430000, size: Size(1920.0, 1080.0),
  position: 0:10:55.430000, caption: Instance of 'Caption', buffered: [DurationRange(start:
  0:00:00.000000, end: 0:10:55.430000)], isPlaying: false, isLooping: false, isBuffering:
  falsevolume: 1.0, errorDescription: null))
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for VideoPlayerController:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This VideoPlayerScreen widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: VideoPlayerScreen
  dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#fe7c2], MediaQuery]
  state: _VideoPlayerScreenState#4559e
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#e44a5]
  state: OverlayState#cf68b(entries: [OverlayEntry#517dd(opaque: true; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#87d9a(opaque: false; maintainState: true)])
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4211:11)
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4226:6)
#2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1260:14)
#3      _VideoPlayerScreenState._listener (package:flow/widget/page/video_player.dart:52:7)
#4      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:209:21)
...
The VideoPlayerController sending notification was: VideoPlayerController#619c5(VideoPlayerValue(duration: 0:10:55.430000, size: Size(1920.0, 1080.0), position: 0:10:55.430000, caption: Instance of 'Caption', buffered: [DurationRange(start: 0:00:00.000000, end: 0:10:55.430000)], isPlaying: false, isLooping: false, isBuffering: falsevolume: 1.0, errorDescription: null))
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/ExoPlayerImpl(24022): Release 569e95d [ExoPlayerLib/2.9.6] [tissot_sprout, Mi A1, Xiaomi, 28] [goog.exo.core]
E/BufferQueueProducer(24022): [SurfaceTexture-0-24022-9] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
D/SurfaceUtils(24022): disconnecting from surface 0x70a0b7e010, reason disconnectFromSurface
```

**Here is my code:**

```
class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;

  const VideoPlayerScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.videoPlayerController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  bool _buttonEnabled = false;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  int playBackTime = 0;
  //VoidCallback _listener;
  void _listener() {
    if (_videoPlayerController.value.position ==
        _videoPlayerController.value.duration) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            _buttonEnabled = true;
          });
        }
      });
    }
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        playBackTime = _videoPlayerController.value.position.inSeconds;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _videoPlayerController = widget.videoPlayerController;
    _videoPlayerController
      ..addListener(_listener)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        _videoPlayerController.play();
        setState(() {});
      });
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      //DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
    AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final length = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          _videoPlayerController.value.initialized
              ? _playerWidget()
              : Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
          Visibility(
            visible: _buttonEnabled,
            child: Container(),
          
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  _playAndPauseButton() {
    return InkWell(
      child: Icon(
        _videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
        size: 25,
      ),
      onTap: () {
        _videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying
            ? _videoPlayerController.pause()
            : _videoPlayerController.play();
      },
    );
  }

  _slider() {
    final length = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      width: length.width * 0.85,
      child: SliderTheme(
        data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
          activeTrackColor: Colors.black,
          inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
          trackHeight: 1.0,
          thumbColor: Colors.yellow,
          thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 6.0),
        ),
        child: Slider(
            max: _videoPlayerController.value.duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
            min: 0.0,
            value: playBackTime.toDouble(),
            onChanged: (v) {
              _videoPlayerController.seekTo(Duration(seconds: v.toInt()));
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  _playerWidget() {
    final length = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        final snackBar = SnackBar(
          content: Container(
            height: length.height * 0.02,
            width: length.width,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                _playAndPauseButton(),
                _slider(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      },
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
        child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    widget.videoPlayerController.pause();
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.videoPlayerController.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode();
    AutoOrientation.portraitUpMode();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to dispose `videoController`:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    widget.videoPlayerController?.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController.removeListener(_listener);
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Finally change `void _listener()` to :

```
void _listener() {
    if (_videoPlayerController.value.position ==
        _videoPlayerController.value.duration) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            _buttonEnabled = true;
          });
        }
      });
    }
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((__) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          playBackTime = _videoPlayerController.value.position.inSeconds;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I have updated my code. Can you please check if there is an issue with my code. Or provide me with an example code where you use a video player, when clicked on a button a video has to play in landscape mode, and when pop back to the previous page the app should be in portrait mode.

Comment: Prefect! Thank you so much for your help. The error is gone and my app is working all fine. Such a relief.