# Flutter web: crash when reloading page with parameters in browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Dear Flutter community,

I have application with main and detail screen. Detail screen has route arguments.
However, when during testing, I open detail page, and then press "Reload", the application crashes.

The error is: "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build"

Is there common/standard solution or logic to implement it?
Business case example: user opened session to look at some material, then after some minutes he reloads screen to see material updates.

PD. Sorry I am not working on a project anymore, so cannot prodide any details

Comment: Have you set your hosting as single page only?

Comment: Hi Andrea, do you know what flutter is about? There is no hosting at all at this moment. I created application with two views, similar to what is described here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments . However, as web version is recent and almost in beta, I think there is no clear indication, what happens, when you start your app not from the main page. Other frameworks have hooks here, which allows you navigation back to main page or restore state. Here it just crashes

Comment: Yes sure, but since your question is kinda vague i needed to understand what's the underlying problem. In your first edit you didn't specified what error whas about. Now its clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The error here is that you are using methods like setState during your build. Set state is a method that can be used **only** in callbacks. So here you are calling this method in the wrong place.

1. If you need to initialize the state of a widget according to a value that you have somewhere locally use the method **initState()**.
2. If you need to retrieve data from remote I suggest you a **FutureBuilder** or a **StreamBuilder**.
3. If you are "forced" to use setState inside the build method, use the WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback (passing the context if you need it):

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context){
       WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState((){/*code here*/}));
       return Container(/*container is just a widget example, use your widgets*/);
}
```

Lastly, always put the stacktrace in your question because, when you have an error in flutter, the stacktrace is usually very precise and it allows to understand where the issue is raised.

Here you can find a similar issue if you need an example: [setState called during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825843/flutter-setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build)

Comment: Hi Andrea, sorry, but I am not calling setState myself anywhere in the code. I just have a StatefulWidget ->Page, which receives argument via Navigator.pushNamed. Then inside a widget "build" I read the parameter:
      someArguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of your error, at least we can navigate the issue properly